# Hybrid MPI/GPU code

Tags: opencl, mpi, gpu

I have done a MPI and GPU version of diffusion equation.

In MPI version, I compute next values by doing a decomposition of the grid and each process represents a sub-grid.

In GPU/OpenCL version, I compute next values by converting 2D grid to 1D and looping of the global index of this 1D grid to achieve the update of all grid.

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to mix these both versions, i.e to assign a sub-grid for each MPI process and into the sub-grid, compute the values with GPU/OpenCL.

I think that it's only feasible if GPU is able to share its ressources between different MPI processes (I have only a GPU device)

Anyone could tell me if actually this is possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the GPU can be shared between multiple processes. It's still just one resource so if you had it reasonably well utilized before with one process then don't expect much scaling since now your processes are competing for a single resource. Worst case is performance actually gets worse, if you oversubscribe the GPU. Another issue to watch out for is GPU memory usage.

Comment: Thanks, so in my MPI code, do I have to initialize GPU only once at the beginning of my code ( for all MPI processes, with clGetPlatformIDs, clGetDeviceIDs,  clCreateContext OpenCL functions ...) or do I need to do it only for one MPI process (for example rank 0 with a condition "if(rank==0) then {initialize_GPU()}) ?

Comment: Per process, assuming MPI process == OS process. If MPI process == OS thread, then just once.

Comment: How can I distinguish an OS process and OS thread ? I use only in my code MPI processes, in its standard form.

Comment: OS processes will show up in Task Manager (or your platform equivalent); OS threads all live under a single process.